# Trying to get 3 individual Integers out of 3 component pickerView

Tags: swift, xcode, view, picker

I am new coding and have hit my first major roadblock. Hoping someone can help. I am trying to make a boxing round timer. I have gotten the pickerview to correctly display the number of rounds, time, and rest. However, I can not find a way to get the numbers out of the code using didSelectRow. I feel like I am missing a variable or something, but I really am not sure. Thanks so much for any help! Here is what I have so far

Edit: I am using three different picker views. One for the rounds, one for the timer per round, and one for the rest time between rounds. I would prefer to keep it that way if possible!

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{

```
@IBOutlet weak var roundsPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var timePicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var restPicker: UIPickerView!

var roundsPickerOptions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
var timePickerOptions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var restPickerOptions = [30, 60, 90, 120]

var round = 0
var time = 0
var rest = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    
    roundsPicker.delegate = self
    roundsPicker.dataSource = self
    timePicker.delegate = self
    timePicker.dataSource = self
    restPicker.delegate = self
    restPicker.dataSource = self
    
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
}
    
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            return roundsPickerOptions.count
        } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
            return timePickerOptions.count
        } else {
            return restPickerOptions.count
        }
    }

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        return "\(roundsPickerOptions[row]) rounds"
    }else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
        return "\(timePickerOptions[row]) min."
    }else {
        return "\(restPickerOptions[row]) sec."
    }
}
```

//Here is where I get lost! I don't even know what to write!!!

```
private func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow: Int, inComponent: Int) -> Int {
    
    if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        return round
    }else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
        return time
    }else {
        return rest
    }
}
```

Comment: `didSelectRow` shouldn't have a return value (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate/1614371-pickerview). Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish? Your question said "I can not find a way to get the numbers out of the code using didSelectRow" but it is unclear what "get the numbers of out the code" means. To do a calculation with them? To display them somewhere else?

Comment: It *might* be helpful to know that you can query a picker at any time for it's selected row: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview/1614369-selectedrow

Answer (score 0):

private func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow: Int, inComponent: Int) {

```
if pickerView.tag == 1 {
    round = roundsPickerOptions[didSelectRow]
}else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
    time = timePickerOptions[didSelectRow]
}else {
    rest = restPickerOptions[didSelectRow]
}
```

}